# Invalid XML Data begin and end tag mismatch

Tags: xml

My XML File already has CDATA on the line of error but still gets invalid end tag or mismatched.

`<tagsample><!CDATA[  .... .... ... ... somewhere here lies the culprit character &lt;br /&gt;]]></tagsample>`

Any simple solution to this?

Comment: Almost certainly, it means the sequence `]]>` appears somewhere "inside" that CDATA section.

Comment: I cannot find any with that sequence they are all either normal human words or &lt;br /&gt; but no ]]>